# Troca de carácter numa posição - sql

Tags: sql, firebird

To querendo substituir o terceiro carácter de um string no firebird, exemplo: 00028 por 00128, 00029 por 00129...
Alguém poderia me ajudar, tentei ver por replace, mas não consigo determinar a posição

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O firebird tem a função overlay.

```
overlay ('00029' placing '1' from 3)
```

Site com a documentação e mais exemplos: [overlay](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc-overlay.html)

Outro exemplo seria para **oracle**, onde é possível usar uma `expressão regular`.

```
SELECT regexp_replace('00029','(^.{2})(.{1})(.*)$','\1X\3') FROM dual;
```

Neste caso, coloquei um "**X**" para marcar onde deverá ser inserido o novo número. O primeiro `{2}` é a posição da troca e o `{1}` é a quantidade de letras a serem substituídas.

Comment: Cara obrigado Reinaldo, não conhecia essa função do firebird, funcionou certinho, vlw